# Self hosted Owin ASP.NET web api only accepting localhost connections

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, web-applications, owin

I am trying to get a self hosted owin console application listening to remote access, and not only localhost.

Code looks like this:

```
//Start API in main()
string domainAddress = "http://10.17.5.42:8080/";

using (WebApp.Start(url: domainAddress))
{
    Console.WriteLine("API started: " + domainAddress);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(-1);
}
```

```
class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        HttpConfiguration CONFIG = new HttpConfiguration();
        CONFIG.EnableCors();
        CONFIG.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "StatusServerAPI",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{data}",
            defaults: new { data = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        appBuilder.UseWebApi(CONFIG);
    }
}
```

but when i look at `netstat -a` it only showes me this:

```
Port    Local Adress           Remote Adress          Status  
TCP     10.17.5.42:8080        username:0             LISTEN
```

Edit:
Running as administrator or `netsh http add urlacl url=http://10.17.5.42:8080/ user=username` didnt work...

Comment: Try start it with admin privileges and see what happens. Normal user process are not allowed to open listening ports on non-local addresses and being reachable from the outside. If you don’t want to start your process with admin privileges, give your user the the permission to accept non-local connections via [netsh add urlacl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/http/add-urlacl).

Comment: @ckuri Neither admin privileges nor netsh http add urlacl changed anything... Still not listening on * : *